# Upload File to User's Google Drive Account

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

So I'm creating this small app which is a standalone Vue SPA for frontend and Laravel API only backend (using sanctum).

I want to do the following...
User uploads one or multiple files -> Backend receives it -> They get stored in the USER'S Google Drive account.

I know this is possible (at least for Dropbox) because I am a consumer of such service.
Creative market syncs files with your Dropbox on demand.

And Google allows 'apps' to access your drive to store data.
I've myself encountered such apps, where you are asked to provide access to an app in order to allow it to access your Google information.

So I think it should be possible with GDrive as well.

Please help, I've been searching about this, but unable to a good resource for this.
I've mostly found how to upload them to MY own drive.

Another problem is, in Laravel disks are hard coded, whereas in case of my app, the disk (Drive account) will change dynamically depending on user. How would one go about implementing something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but I thought [flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/) might have a pre-made Google Drive adapter. It doesn't. A [quick search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=flysystem+google+drive+adapter&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.0.4) led me to a [community made adapter](https://github.com/nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive). Then that page linked to [a repo about laravel & google drive](https://github.com/ivanvermeyen/laravel-google-drive-demo).

Comment: & if you weren't able to find it, the [official g drive documentation is here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk). You'll have to authenticate users (with OAuth, I'm assuming). They have sdks for Node.js, Python, Java, & Javascipt, it looks like. You might be able to find a community-made package for php [on github](https://github.com/search?q=php+google+drive)

Comment: Hi Reed,
Thank you for responding.
I had come across this community made package, and maybe they are useful, I've also gone through the docs a bit. 
But what I need help is, with the entire process. like what approach should I take in order to make my users "allow access" to my app to use THEIR Google Drive? And once that is done, how to save the files they upload into a specific folder structure.

Then comes the problem with Laravel Disks and fly-system, how to make and use disks dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**You can start by taking a look at the Drive API v3 Quickstarts [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).**

As for uploading a file to Drive, you will have the make the following request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files
```

With the following `uploadType` depending on the upload type you are performing:

- `uploadType=media` > for a small media file (5 MB or less) without supplying metadata;
- `uploadType=multipart` > for a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata that describes the file, in a single request;
- `uploadType=resumable` > for large files (greater than 5 MB) and when there's a high chance of network interruption.

Depending on the exact request you choose to make, you will also have to supply a request body.

You can also test the Drive API v3 and make requests directly by accessing the API Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create).

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk);
- [Drive API v3 Manage Uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads);
- [Drive API v3 Files:create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create).

Comment: Hi, Thanks...while this answers on HOW to upload a file, my question is regarding how to set up my app in such a way, so that I can upload a file to my user's Google Drive account